# Find all $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}, f\in C^1$ so that $q, f(q)$ has the same denominator as $q$

Tags: calculus, elementary-number-theory, derivatives, divisibility

> Find all continuously differentiable functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ so that for every rational number $q, f(q)$ is rational and has the same denominator as $q$ in lowest terms (to simplify, say $f(q)$ has the same denominator as $q$).

Clearly $-x + n$ and $x+n$ work for any integer $n$. But I'm not sure how to prove they're the only ones.  I found the solution below, but I don't understand why $f((an+1)/(bn)) = f(a/b)$ for sufficiently large n has denominator $b$ rather than $bn$. Also why does that yield a contradiction?

> Similarly, why can't $|c|$ be greater than 1? I don't understand their explanation. Specifically, I believe it's not true that for $n$ sufficiently large $\dfrac{an+1}{bn}$ has denominator bn.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f\left(\frac{an+1}{bn}\right) = f\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)$. Because the denominator of $q$ and $f(q)$ is equal in lowest terms, and we know $\gcd(a, b) = 1$ that implies $\frac{a}{b}$ is in simplest form, so $f\left(\frac{an+1}{bn}\right) = f\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) = \frac{a'}{b}$ such that $\gcd(a', b) = 1$. But this means that we must divide the numerator and denominator of $\frac{an+1}{bn}$ by $n$ to get its simplest form, contradicting $n \nmid an + 1$.

For your second question, notice that if $n = k|c|$ then
\begin{align}
f\left(\frac{an+1}{bn}\right) = f\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) + \frac{c}{bn} = \frac{a'}{b} + \frac{c}{bk|c|} = \frac{a'}{b} \pm \frac{1}{bk} = \frac{a'k \pm 1}{bk}.
\end{align}
So we must divide the numerator and denominator of the fraction $\frac{an+1}{bn} = \frac{ak|c| + 1}{bk|c|}$ *at least* by $|c|$ to get its simplest form. A contradiction. (The expression "at least" appeared because $\frac{a'k \pm 1}{bk}$ may not be in lowest terms.)